# How to render background image in header with Semantic-UI-React <Container>

Tags: reactjs, image, containers, semantic-ui-react

I'm using a Semantic-UI-React theme and want to customize it with an opacity background image that covers the full header. I'll then but a logo and text on top of that. I can't seem to get the image attributes in `<Header>` working. I've tried many combinations.

Here's my `<Container>` and `<Header>` code in `React`:

```
  <Container>
  <Header
      as='h1'
      inverted
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${"images/image_03-1024x320.jpg"})`,
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        fontSize: mobile ? '2em' : '4em',
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        marginBottom: 0,
        marginTop: mobile ? '1.5em' : '3em',
      }}
      />
  </Container>
)
```

The result is a tiny  sliver of the image in the `Header`.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure without a working example to inspect but I suspect you need to add a width and height.  Also you may need to make the `h1` have a display of `inline-block`.  Try this:

```
<Container>
    <Header
        as='h1'
        inverted
        style={{
            width: 1024,
            height: 320,
            display: 'inline-block',
            opacity: 0.5,
            backgroundImage: `url(${"images/image_03-1024x320.jpg"})`,
            backgroundSize: 'cover',
            fontSize: mobile ? '2em' : '4em',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
            marginBottom: 0,
            marginTop: mobile ? '1.5em' : '3em',
        }}
    >
       Hello World
    </Header>
</Container>
```

Comment: Oh yes that's the one! Now if I want to make the image opaque and then add text on top without being affected, where would that go in the attributes?

Comment: Add `opacity: 0.5,` and put text within your `<Header>` element.

Comment: Yeah I've got opacity working but anything placed on top of the background image gets affected as well.

Comment: Then add a child element and style that differently, try: `<Header><div style={{}}>Some text</div></Header>`.  Did my answer and comments help?